# Oracle unique index with null and special value allowed

Tags: database, oracle, unique-constraint

I have a unique index today that allows all null values for column `ssn`, but if it has a value it has to be unique in combination with `server`.

Now I want to change it so that it both allow null values and a special defined value.

The old index was created like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_SSN ON person (
    CASE WHEN ssn IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE server END,
    ssn);
```

Now I would like to change it into something like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_SSN ON person (
    CASE WHEN (ssn IS NULL OR ssn = 'SPECIAL_VALUE') THEN NULL ELSE server END,
    ssn);
```

That doesn't work though. With that index I'm still allowed to add null-values. But I am only allowed to add one row where ssn = 'SPECIAL_VALUE', on the second one I get the error:

ORA-00001: unique constraint (APP_DB.UQ_SSN) violated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the issue because when `ssn = 'SPECIAL_VALUE'` it creates the index on `null, 'SPECIAL_VALUE'` and while you insert new record then also it creates the index on `null, 'SPECIAL_VALUE'` which is not allowed.

You must use some other column like `PK_COLUMN` when there is `ssn = 'SPECIAL_VALUE'` so that `null, pk_col` will be different for each row.

Try `case..when` in the second column of the index.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_SSN ON person (
    server,
    CASE WHEN ssn is null or ssn = 'SPECIAL_VALUE' THEN to_char(id) ELSE ssn END);
```

**Note**: You can use `CASE .. WHEN` without else. so I have slightly modified it.

Comment: My PK column is named id, and is of type `NUMBER(38)`.
With your suggestion I get the error: `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got NCHAR`

Comment: Ok, Updated it in the answer. Have a look

Comment: I get another error: `ORA-12704: character set mismatch`.
But now we're on completely different errors.

Comment: Means you must have some different characterset in the ssn. You can use `to_nchar(id)` in the index.

Comment: @orderlyfashion If you are storing the SSN without punctuation then this can fail when your ID matches an SSN.

Comment: @MT0 Thanks for letting me know. That's not the case though. :)